How many iOS live activities for specific app can exist at the same time? Is there any limit on how many activities from different apps can co-exist?
I am able to create few (four-five) iOS live activities from a single app at the same time and also we do have control on each activity.

When I am going to create more, it gives following error:

Error requesting Parking Live Activity The operation couldn’t be
completed. Maximum number of activities for target already exists.

Conclusion

We can create few live activities from single app and they can co-exist. In my app, there will be no more than two live activities at the same time, so there is no hurdle upto this point.

Problem

Suppose user has already ongoing live activities from another apps
e.g. for an ongoing matches of different sports and also a activity for an online
food order. In that case, will it prevent me starting an activity of my app. Will it impact the on-going live activities of my app?
I have had a look at
apple documentation but there is no information on such a
limit/condition. I certainly need to inform user about the ongoing activity.

